# What does a[ a[ i ] ] do in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning permutation in Java and I cannot understand this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Permutation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {0, 3, 2, 4, 1};
        int[] ans = new int[4];

        ans[0] = nums[nums[1]];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));

    }
}
```

this code prints

```
[4, 0, 0, 0]
```

I get that the `nums[nums[1]]` is providing the address of the value `1` present in `nums` array.

But,
***can someone please provide me with more context on this?***

Comment: `nums[1]` is `3`, `nums[nums[1]]` is `nums[3]` is `4`.

Comment: `providing the address of the value 1 present in nums array.` - Not really, it takes the value at index 1 (=3) and then looks up index 3 - which is the value of 4.

Comment: 1. `nums = {0, 3, 2, 4, 1}, ans = {0,0,0,0}`, 2. `nums[1] = 3` 3. `nums[nums[1]] = nums[3] = 4` 4. `ans = {4, 0, 0, 0}` voila! ;)

Comment: The result being 4 and the index of 1 also being 4 is a coincidence. If you want to find the indexes of the numbers, you need different trick. A common trick for that also involves a "double array access", but in a different way.

Comment: thank you everyone for replying, this helped a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

`a[someExpression]` will do one of four things:

1. return the element of `a` at the index of the numerical result of `someExpression`
2. throw a `NullPointerException` if `a` is `null`
3. throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `someExpression`
   evaluates to an index that doesn't exist in `a` (i.e. less than 0 or bigger than or equal to `a.length`).
4. throw whatever `someExpression` throws, if anything

This is always true, no matter what `someExpression` is. For now we will ignore the error cases and focus only on case #1.

`a[a[i]]` specifically does the above thing twice:

- the inner `a[i]` gets the element of `a` at position `i` and evaluates to its value
- the outer `a[a[i]]` uses the value returned by the value read above and uses it as an index into the array itself.

So in your examples `nums[1]` evaluates to `3`. Then `nums[nums[i]]` is effectively the same as `nums[3]` which will evaluate to `4`.

Comment: sorry, i am late, but thank you very much it helped!